# Format of Textfile?

Tags: linux, windows, textfiles

There was a problem when I copied a Text file from Linux to Windows.
The Text was not as the original, it was shifted to almost one line, also the line break setting couldn't help.
The content was from a website and it was copied in the right format as on the website to the text file on Linux.

I used then on Windows the comandline tool more:

> more < textfile.txt > formatted.txt

So I could get back the original format.

Is there some configuration which might hold the format directly when copying the file between Linux and Windows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before copying, use the Linux utility [unix2dos](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unix2dos1.html): UNIX to DOS text file format converter.

After copying back from Windows, use the Linux utility [dos2unix](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html): DOS/MAC to UNIX text file format converter.

Other utilities and programming libraries can perform this line-ending conversion as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Is there a way to do it for multiple files, thru the mentioned tool ?

Comment: Just specify all file names on the command line.  From the manual:  "Convert and replace a.txt. Convert and replace b.txt. `unix2dos a.txt b.txt`"

Comment: Yes, thank you, I will try it. Maybe something with *.txt could work too.